# which drive do I mount

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, ubuntu-8.04, fdisk

I have a system hdd

then two raid1 hard drives

I see that sda1 is the system drive

but when i do a fdisk -l I get the following results

so which of the following do i need to mount to get the "raid" drive and not the individual hdd?

```
root@Mxxxx-PDC:/etc/samba# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 251.0 GB, 251000193024 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30515 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000762dc

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       30328   243609628+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2           30329       30515     1502077+   5  Extended
/dev/sda5           30329       30515     1502046   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 400.0 GB, 400088457216 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 48641 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1       48641   390708801   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdc: 250.0 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009f4b2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *           1         255     2048256   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdc2             256       30401   242147745   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdd: 250.0 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b7f4c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1   *           1         255     2048256   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdd2             256       30401   242147745   fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may not have done this right but i just mounted sdb1 and it seems fine

Comment: That is a separate 400GB partition, and not the RAID array.

Answer (score 5):

e) None of the above

You want one of the `/dev/md*` or `/dev/mapper/*` entries instead.

Comment: Kudos for making me laugh.

Comment: as for your comment below. I dont have these entries when i do a search what do you suggest

Answer (score 4):

You can `cat /proc/mdstat` to identify the md device, which is what you will want to mount.

Comment: i have a proc dir but no mdstat

Comment: Do you have software RAID compiled in the kernel or modules loaded?  Is there data on this RAID, was it ever actually created or are they simply partitions?

Comment: Who knows. I got this box as part of my new job . I went a head and mounted sdb1 and it seems to be working fine

Comment: It will work but now your RAID is effectively broken.  Any changes made to the data have the potential to be lost upon rebuild if you accessed as a RAID.

Comment: @Crash893 by mounting sdb1, you are mounting one of the individual hard disks instead of the RAID drive.